# AngularJs Jcarousel implementation works only after pageresize

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, resize, jcarousel

I have a kind of weird problem here. I took the for my part most fitting Example of JCarousel (http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/) and created a Angular directive out of it.

So far so good, it basically works but I have to trigger one Frame/Window resizeing first, otherwise JS gives me a console error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null - jquery.jcarousel.js:521*

I've made up a smiplyfied jsfiddle here where you can reproduce the problem. The Carousel will work like a charme once you triggered a resize on the "Result" frame or the whole window:

http://jsfiddle.net/nbtw3cnk/4/

I have absolutely no Idea how to solve this, any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

John

### JCarousel directive for AngularJs:

```
var carousel = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            images: "="
        },
        template: '<div class="jcarousel-wrapper"><div class="jcarousel"><ul><li ng-repeat="img in images"><!--<img ng-src="{{img.imageKey}}" />-->{{img.imageKey}}</li></ul></div><a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a><a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a></div>',
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var jcarousel = $('.jcarousel');

            jcarousel.jcarousel({
                    wrap: 'circular'
                });

            $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
                .jcarouselControl({
                    target: '-=1'
                });

            $('.jcarousel-control-next')
                .jcarouselControl({
                    target: '+=1'
                });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload when the images attribute has actually been bound successfully. Calling reload is a side-effect of resizing the browser window.  That's why your carousel worked after resizing.

You should also avoid using jQuery class selectors within an angular directive.  It can cause problems when multiple instances of your directive are on the same page.  Here is a modified working version of your directive ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmarrapese/oj814xun/)):

```
angular.module('testApp', []).directive('carousel', carousel);

function carousel() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            images: "="
        },
        template: '<div class="jcarousel-wrapper"><div class="jcarousel"><ul><li ng-repeat="img in images"><!--<img ng-src="{{img.imageKey}}" />-->{{img.imageKey}}</li></ul></div><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a></div>',
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var container = $(element);
            var carousel = container.children('.jcarousel')

            carousel.jcarousel({
                wrap: 'circular'
            });

            scope.$watch(attrs.images, function (value) {
                carousel.jcarousel('reload');
            });

            container.children('.jcarousel-control-prev')
                .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

            container.children('.jcarousel-control-next')
                .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT:** Note that the above code uses jQuery's `$()` syntax.  Normally, you will want to use `angular.element()` in an angular application.  If jQuery exists when angular is initially brought in, `angular.element()` will just alias `$()`.  However, jsFiddle included angular prior to including jQuery.  Therefore, angular falls back on jqLite, which doesn't understand `.jcarousel()`.

**EDIT 2:** updated the next/previous hrefs to play nicely with hash routing.